# I can not see my MongoDB collections on Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I can not see my MongoDB collections on my Atlas account when I log in, **weiredly** when I log in through Google chrome *incognito* mode I can see everything just fine.

*Google Chrome*

[image]